# Can We create custom build feature in teamcity 10?

Tags: teamcity, udeploy

Right now we are uploading artifacts using udeploy cmd from Teamcity version 10. Can we create a custom build feature in teamcity for common tasks to avoid the manual stuff like
    udeploy  ??
    common copy tasks
    If it is possible, will be worthfull..

Thanks...!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a TeamCity [meta-runner](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Working+with+Meta-Runner) to encapsulate the uploading logic into a build step and configure it via a small set of parameters (if at all necessary).

If you need a build feature (which is much like build step, just you can add it in the template and do not need to manage the order of the build steps), this is possible via creating a TeamCity plugin which requires writing Java code.